# how to strip the text from xpath expression

Tags: java, xpath

I have the following **xpath** expression

```
//pre//strong[@class='messageText']
```

which give me out put of

```
"this output O/13-1405 is valid for this scenario"
```

what I need is to get only `"O/13-1405"` this should be generic as every test gets different output in the text

Comment: Use either regex or magic.

Comment: That's where I am struggling - I am not getting the full xpath with regex to use it in my test automation

Answer (score 0):

If this pattern is fixed (or you can find a fixed and distinct pattern directly around the wanted substring), you can use `substring-before` and `substring-after` to cut down the result:

```
substring-after(substring-before(//pre//strong[@class='messageText'], ' is valid for this scenario'), 'this output ')
```

If the output is always of the exactly same length, you could also use `substring($text, $start, $length)`.

---

If you need to grep out of arbitrary text and need regular expressions, you either need to use Java code or embed another XPath processor which supports at least XPath 2.0 (Saxon can be embedded quite easily).